Chrome extension: Persist context menu
Goal

Persist context menu for all users after new release.
Set up context menu upon browser starting up

Current set up
Background.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'Main',
        id: 'Main',
        contexts: ['selection']
    });
});

To my understanding runtime.oninstalled fires when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version (source).
This seems ideal as the context menu I am adding will be for next version of the extension. However, will it persist thereafter? Not sure if I should use runtime.onStartup().

It persists in Chromium/Chrome, but it doesn't in Firefox with MV2 extensions where you need to recreate the menu at startup.
